# Show $\frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(e^{i\theta})\cos^2(\frac{\theta}{2})d\theta = 2f(0)+f'(0)$ when $f\in A(|z|<1+\varepsilon)$.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

Saw this question in a test, but got stuck, here is my attempt:

\begin{align}
\frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(e^{i\theta})\cos^2\bigg(\frac{\theta}{2}\bigg)\,d\theta &= \frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(e^{i\theta})\frac{1+\cos(\theta)}{2}\,d\theta \\
&= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(e^{i\theta}) +  \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(e^{i\theta})\cos(\theta)\,d\theta \\
&= 2f(0) + \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(e^{i\theta})\cos(\theta)\,d\theta .
\end{align}

Now it only remains to show $$
\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(e^{i\theta})\cos(\theta)\,d\theta = f'(0),
$$
but this where I am stuck.  From Cauchy's formula:
\begin{align}
f'(0) &= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{f(e^{i\theta})}{e^{2i\theta}}ie^{i\theta}\,d\theta \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{f(e^{i\theta})}{e^{i\theta}}\,d\theta \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(e^{i\theta})e^{-i\theta}\,d\theta \\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(e^{i\theta})\cos(\theta)\,d\theta - \frac{i}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(e^{i\theta})\sin(\theta)\,d\theta,
\end{align}
Which is clearly not
$$
\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(e^{i\theta})\cos(\theta)\,d\theta$ unless $\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(e^{i\theta})\sin(\theta)\,d\theta = 0.
$$
I haven't a clue as
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(e^{i\theta})\sin(\theta)\,d\theta = 0
$$
or whether this actually makes sense. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you forget the half-angle in your initial power reduction on $cos^2(\frac{\theta}{2})$?

Comment: No, the identity is correct

Comment: Oh, my mistake!

Comment: I edited your post a bit to clean it up slightly. Use `\begin{align}` + `\end{align}` for a long chain of equalities. It's a little easier to read. :)

Comment: I'd probably make this problem a bit simpler by noting that $\displaystyle\cos(\theta) = \frac{1}{2}(e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta})$ so that your first equation becomes $$\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(e^{i\theta})\bigg(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} e^{i\theta} + \frac{1}{4} e^{-i\theta}\bigg)\,d\theta.$$ Then making the change of variable $e^{i\theta} \mapsto z$, you'd have $$\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{\partial B(0,1)} \bigg(\frac{1}{2}\frac{f(z)}{z} + \frac{1}{4}f(z) + \frac{1}{4}\frac{f(z)}{z^2}\bigg)\,dz.$$ I don't think I've made a mistake here, but you should check it.

Comment: Ah whoops I'm missing some $i$s in there, I think, but not a big deal.